# Screen Scraping in PHP with login

Tags: php, screen-scraping

Looking around for a solution to this, I have found different methods. Some use regex, some use DOM scripting or something.

I want to go to a site, log in, fill out a form and then check if the form sent. The logging in part is the part I can't find anything on.

Anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just to note, this was going to be a web app so couldn't really use a gui program as some of the answers are suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Perl's LWP library (I know it isn't PHP, but it's very useful for screen scraping, web unit testing, and such):

- [Perl LWP at CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.800/lib/LWP.pm)
- [LWP::Simple tutorial](http://www.perlmeme.org/tutorials/lwp.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree with Les.  Curl + Charles (or Fiddler, Firefox's Tamper Data extension, wireshark, etc.) is the way I've always done this.  The one trick I've found is that some sites require a three step process:

1. Hit the login page with a GET request first to get any session ids, cookies, and/or required fields (e.g. .net sites have __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION).
2. Once you have these values, then you post to the login page
3. Finally, request whatever resource you're after.

Don't plan on curl's cookie jar and cookie file being much help.  You'll probably be best off parsing out the session id and cookies from the headers using a simple regex.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with some sort of scriptable browser if you need to do a lot of GUI stuff. If you need to use PHP, check out curl: https://www.php.net/curl

Answer (score 1):

what I usually do is fire up [charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) go through the login process in a browser and record the raw requests. Copy+paste the requests and throw them through [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (with some small adjustments according to the responses).

Answer (score 0):

I have fair bit of experience in this. I used to use Curl but it is no fun using it. In particular many times sites exchange XSRF tokens, or pass hidden variables, or set all kinds of cookies. Tracking all this with Curl becomes difficult. Atleast for me.

I then explored Selenium and I love it. There are 2 things- 1) install Selenium IDE (works only in Firefox). 2) Install Selenium RC Server

After starting Selenium IDE, go to the site that you are trying to automate and start recording events that you do on the site. Think it as recording a macro in the browser. Afterwards, you get the code output for the language you want.

Just so you know Browsermob uses Selenium for load testing and for automating tasks on browser.

I've uploaded a ppt that I made a while back. This should save you a good amount of time- http://www.4shared.com/get/tlwT3qb_/SeleniumInstructions.html

In the above link select the option of regular download.